# Does Tezos have a wallet API that automatically generates wallets for new users?

Tags: api, address

Does Tezos have a wallet API that automatically generates wallets for new users ?
Where can I find documentation about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API as in a hosted application sitting on a server that anyone can call? no, this wouldn't be secure. There are many tools available that will do this offline, depending what it is you are doing

Creating a wallet, basically, is the result of some randomly generated numbers and some cryptography. This creates a private / public key pair completely offline in a safe manner. To use the wallet, you simply send a transaction to the Tezos node to tell it what your public key is and to register it on-chain

If you want to do this in

- typescript / javasctipt, you can look at Taquito: https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/blob/master/packages/taquito/src/wallet/wallet.ts
- Swift, you can look at kukai-crypto-swift: https://github.com/kukai-wallet/kukai-crypto-swift
- If you want to do it in a command line environment, you can use the Tezos CLI: https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtouse.html#a-simple-wallet

Comment: I mean I have a service with other chains and Tezos integrated. Now user xyz wants to deposit into his Tezos account and must generate eacg time a new address (to avoid address reusage) For the user its one click. But how would this be achieved? I suppose similar like exchanges generate addresses for users.

Comment: @Zitar so there is no other way to generate addresses, other than using one of these tools or copying what they do into another language. In the case of exchanges, they would be using one of these too, likely the official CLI. They would have that installed somewhere on some server, not exposed to outside traffic, that would create the address and store the keys in some traditional secure database. Then they would have a property/column of the username that owns the address so it can be looked up when they login